# A view height is 568 on 3.5-inch screen

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I need to create a view with a scroll view and a page control in it, and place 7 views inside scroll view.
To lay out subviews inside the scroll view I use pure Auto layout Approach, that is described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013309-CH1-TNTAG3).

So I have my controller with XIB file (I don't use storyboards here) that is pretty simple: it's a `UIScrollView` and `UIPageControl` with all constraints set up.

And I have a XIB for a `UIView` subclass `Slide` which has 2 `UIImageViews` and 1 `UILabel`, and there's also some constraints.

To add some views to `UIScrollView` I use this code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    scrollView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    var pSlide: Slide?
    for var i = 0; i < 7; i++ {
        var slide = Slide(frame: self.view.bounds, imageName: "slide-\(i+1)-bg", text: NSLocalizedString("slides_\(i+1)", comment: ""))
        slide.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        scrollView.addSubview(slide)


        var dict: [NSObject : AnyObject] = ["currentSlide" : slide]
        if let previousSlide = pSlide {
            dict["previousSlide"] = previousSlide
            let constraintsHorizontal = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[previousSlide][currentSlide]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: dict)
            scrollView.addConstraints(constraintsHorizontal)

            let constraintsVertical = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[currentSlide]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: dict)
            scrollView.addConstraints(constraintsVertical)
        } else {
            let constraintsVertical = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[currentSlide]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: dict)
            scrollView.addConstraints(constraintsVertical)

            let constraintsLeft = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[currentSlide]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: dict)
            scrollView.addConstraints(constraintsLeft)
        }

        if i == 6 {
            let constraintsRight = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[currentSlide]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: dict)
            scrollView.addConstraints(constraintsRight)
        }

        pSlide = slide
    }

    pageControl.numberOfPages = numberOfSlides
    view.layoutSubviews()
}
```

In this piece of code I create a `Slide` instance, and set all necessary constraints to it, according to pure Auto Layout approach.

`init()` method of the `Slide` class looks like this:

```
init(frame: CGRect, imageName: String, text: String) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Slide", owner: self, options: nil)
    self.addSubview(self.view)

    self.view.frame = frame
    self.layoutIfNeeded()

    println("Frame is \(frame); view.frame is \(self.view.frame)")

    backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    textLabel.text = text

}
```

I hoped that

```
self.view.frame = frame
self.layoutIfNeeded()
```

will help me but no. The problem is, on 3.5 inch screen all my UIScrollView subviews have the height of 568, which is the normal height for 4 inch display, but not for 3.5 inch.

I'm checking the height in `viewDidAppear(animated:)` method. But, in `init()` method of `Slide` class the height appears to be ok — 480.

I'm trying to solve it for second day already, and still nothing works. I know that this may be much more simple to implement without using Auto Layout and Interface Builder, but I need to do it with these.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your problem, but it looks like you are reinventing [`UIPageViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/). Before you spend another day you should check that class out.

Comment: how do you define contentsize? note that with autolayout the contentsize is defined from constraints!

Comment: @MatthiasBauch post your comment as an answer please. I should always check new stuff in each iOS version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `UIPageViewController` instead of all this mess, and it works just fine.